# If name & operator matches, update the recent value, not working in the second iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, web

I have an array of filters, where i get the name of filter, operator & value
e.g.

```
[{name="pricing.price", op="gte", value=10000}, {name="pricing.price", op="gte", value=10000}]
```

when the user refreshes after applying the filter, the last filters are saved into this.savedFilters

and after the refresh, the user can add new filters or modify the existing filters.

add new filters -> works fine
modify existing filters -> NOT working fine

I made a function, which is partially doing the job, if I am running it, it's updating the value only once, and then next time I update, it's not updating anything.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cdr8btwe/

```
//if there are no saved filters, the new filters are the final filters
if (!this.savedFilters) {
          this.finalFilters = this.freshFilters;
        } else {

//concat the new & saved filters & move into a temp array

          this.tempArrayOfFilters =
            this.freshFilters.concat(this.savedFilters);

//forEach loop to check

          this.tempArrayOfFilters.forEach((value) => {
            const key = value['name'] + '_ ' + value['op'];

            if (this.mapping[key]) {
            } else {
              this.finalFilters.push(value);
              this.mapping[key] = true;
            }

          });
        }

        console.log('finalFilters:', this.finalFilters);
```

```
[
{name:"pricing.price",op:"gte",value:1234}, {name:"pricing.price",op:"lte",value:1111}
]
```

When the person is modifying saved filters, 
lets say

```
this.freshfilters = [{"name":"pricing.price","op":"gte","value":5678},
{"name":"pricing.price","op":"gte","value":9999}]
```

output is coming

```
[{name:"pricing.price", op:"gte", value:1234},
{name:"pricing.price", op:"lte", value:1111}]
```

the output should be

```
[{name:"pricing.price",op:"gte",value:5678},{name:"pricing.price",op:"lte",value:9999}]
```

because if name & op is the same, just update the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but hopefully this will be of some use to you.

```
    let arr1 = [{name: "pricing.price", op:"gte", value:1234}];
    let arr2 = [{name: "pricing.price", op:"gte", value:5678}];
    let arr3 = [{name: "pricing.price", op:"lte", value:1111}];
    let arr5 = [{name: "pricing.price", op:"lte", value:9999}];

    let arr4 = []

    arr4 = arr4.concat(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr5);


    final_arr = []
    mapping = {} // truthy mapping of name and p.p

    arr4.forEach((value) => {
    key = value["name"]+'_ '+value["op"]
    final_arr[key] = value;

     //if (mapping[ key ]) {
    //} else {
    //final_arr.push(value)
    mapping[key] = true
    //}

    })

    //Current Output

    /* 
    [
    {name:"pricing.price", op:"gte", value:1234},
    {name:"pricing.price", op:"lte", value:1111}
    ]
    */


    //Expected Output

    /* 
    [
    {"name":"pricing.price","op":"gte","value":5678},
    {"name":"pricing.price","op":"lte","value":9999}
    ]
    */


    console.log('final_arr: ', final_arr)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Larry_Robertson/02ob7sht/6/)